# How I get values from a JSON document in bash?

Tags: bash, json, aws

I want to write a script that finds my unused volumes in AWS. (the 'status' of used volumes is 'in-use').

When I use the aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=status,Values=available
I got the next response for example.

```json
{ "Volumes": [ { "Attachments": [], "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a", "CreateTime": "2022-04-21T08:45:29.704000+00:00", "Encrypted": false, "Size": 1, "SnapshotId": "", "State": "available", "VolumeId": "vol-0e81644ad6193439f", "Iops": 100, "Tags": [ { "Key": "sre", "Value": "test" } ], "VolumeType": "gp2", "MultiAttachEnabled": false } ] }
```

I want to save just the state, volumeId & tags.

Comment: It's unclear what you want the result to look like given the JSON document that you show. Do you still want a JSON document, but with some information removed, or do you want the data in some other format? What should that output look like if the arrays in the JSON document contains more than single elements (the `Volumes` array and the `Tags` array)?

Comment: I want the result looks like
{
"State": "available","VolumeId": "vol-0e81644ad6193439f","Tags": [ { "Key": "sre", "Value": "test" } ]

Comment: They can be in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't use the `aws` command to do this, I would personally use the JSON parser `jq` to extract the wanted data.

```bsh
jq '.Volumes[] | { State: .State, VolumeId: .VolumeId, Tags: .Tags }'
```

For each entry in the `Volumes` array, this would create a new JSON object containing only the fields you want to keep from that entry.

With your given JSON document as input, this would result in

```json
{
  "State": "available",
  "VolumeId": "vol-0e81644ad6193439f",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "sre",
      "Value": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or, if you use `jq -c`:

```json
{"State":"available","VolumeId":"vol-0e81644ad6193439f","Tags":[{"Key":"sre","Value":"test"}]}
```

... which is an equivalent document.

Comment: When I using my script I have 'awsvalue' which contain the dictionary from aws response, so let say I want print  like you mention up . How I combine between jq '.Volumes[] | { State: .State, VolumeId: .VolumeId, Tags: .Tags }' & 'awsvalue' ?

Comment: awsvalue=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=status,Values=available)
###echo ${awsvalue[jq '.Volumes[] | { State: .State, VolumeId: .VolumeId, Tags: .Tags }'] ?

Comment: @AdiIsrael `aws ec2 ... | jq '...'`. There is no need to store the JSON document in an intermediate variable.

Comment: Thanks!!! it helped and I am learning jq , thanks a lot.